# Why does the self in the class always have the previous data?

Tags: python

im new to python and today i had this problem:

say, i have this code incluing two classes named: `slice` and `mat`:

```py
class slice():
    def __init__(self, var:int) -> None:
        self.__var = var
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self.__var

class mat():
    __slices = []
    def __init__(self,var:list) -> None:
        self.__var = var
        for i in var:
            self.__slices.append(slice(i))
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.__var
    @property
    def slices(self):
        return self.__slices

ori_data = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
]

list_mat = []
for i in ori_data:
    list_mat.append(mat(i))
print(len(list_mat))
for i in list_mat:
    print(i.slices)
```

output:

```sh
2
[<__main__.slice object at 0x000002B20597E908>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B205957FC8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C7588>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C76C8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C7508>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D3708>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D37C8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D3808>]
[<__main__.slice object at 0x000002B20597E908>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B205957FC8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C7588>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C76C8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059C7508>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D3708>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D37C8>, <__main__.slice object at 0x000002B2059D3808>]
```

I thought that: the `list_mat` would have 2 mat object(which is true by the output of `print(len(list_mat))`)

And i thought every `mat` object in `list_mat` would have `4 slice` objects and the `var` for  each `slice` obj would be `1 2 3 4` and `5 6 7 8` for each `mat` obj.

But when it came to the actual `mat` object in the `list_mat`,every `mat` have `8 slice` objects and they had the exactly same `8 slice` objects in the memory.

When i debugged, i found that when i created the second `mat` object, in the `__init__`, the `self` already had previous value(which were the `slices` created for the first `mat`). So that when i passed the second list `5 6 7 8` for the constructor, it would just add another `4 slice` objects for the second `mat` which gave me the result of `8 slice` objects.

Another thing is when the second `mat` was created, the `__slice` in the first `mat` changed into the `__slice` in the second `mat`! Actually when i checked the `__init__` function when debugged, i found that the address of the second `mat`'s `self` object, it was the address of the first `mat` object which had beed created already.

There must be some `deepcopy` stuff i have missed.

So to sum:

1: during a for loop, the `self` obj for the `mat` class always has the previous data left by the creation of the first `mat` obj

2: during a for loop, how can i deepcopy and created a whole new obj with everything created new in the memory

Any advice would help!

let me know if you don't understand my question!

Wishes!

Comment: `__slices` is a *class attribute*, since it's initialized in the class body and never reassigned, and therefore shared by every instance of `mat`.  Set it in `.__init__()` instead, to make it an instance attribute.

Comment: bro, i totally forgot this `class attribute` part. And tried your advice already, It worked. Appreciate!!

Comment: There is a built-in class named `slice`. It’s generally a bad idea to name your own variables the same as built-ins.

Comment: got it, apprecite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jasonharper had it right.....

```py
class mat():
    __slices = []
```

This code creates a CLASS LEVEL variable which is shared by all instances of the class.  This is useful for example, if you wanted to have a `object_count` variable which you increment during object creation and decrement during destruction.  But, in your case, you want each `mat` object to have its own `__slices`, so you want to define that variable within `__init__()`:

```py
    def __init__(self,var:list) -> None:
        self.__var = var
        self.__slices = []
```

Comment: I've been learning python and have a comfort level with OOP in other languages. I had no idea that class attributes (similar to static attributes or methods in Java or C++) were created this way. Glad I didn't have to learn this one the hard way. Python is crazy-town sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because class variable `__slices = []` is keep getting updated and keep shared among all class instance. so in last iteration when last element is added then it get reference to all other object (class instance) appended in the list and show this behavior.

More Information, Python [class variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)   are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class.